# Can you save a paypal users information to charge them later REST API?

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to do a type of one click buy within my site using the paypal restsdk. Where the user will be able to somehow add their paypal account and we will just charge their account every time it's appropriate.

I have looked into the [vault](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#store-a-credit-card) but that seems like it's a credit card only option. It would be nice to not force the user to enter a credit card if they already have a paypal account, since paypal may already have a credit card on file, or the user may have a positive paypal balance, etc.

I'm using python with the paypalrestsdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything for that in the REST API, but the Classic API can do it very easily with Express Checkout [Billing Agreements](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/#id094TB0Y0J5Z__id094TB4003HS).

Comment: That looks like the right direction. However, it looks like you need special permission from paypal.

Comment: You just need to request that they enable it for you.  Shouldn't be a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is Avi from PayPal. The PayPal REST API has [billing plans and agreements](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/) too, here are the python [samples](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/tree/master/samples/subscription). This will allow you to charge user at regular intervals.

Charging user's PayPal at arbitrary intervals through web without redirecting to PayPal is unfortunately not supported. If the user is giving consent on a mobile device, you have the option to do [future payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/make-future-payment/). Here is [sample](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/create_future_payment.py) for python sdk.